# 3D boolean assertion fail. "mark" not matching

Tags: cgal

I'm trying to do some 3D boolean operations with CGAL. I have successfully converted my polyhedra to nef polyhedra. However, when ever I try doing a simple union, I get an assertion fail on line 286 of SM_overlayer.h:

```
CGAL error: assertion violation!
Expression : G.mark(v1,0)==G.mark(v2,0)&& G.mark(v1,1)==G.mark(v2,1)
File       : ./CGAL/include/CGAL/Nef_S2/SM_overlayer.h
Line       : 287
```

I tried searching the documentation for "mark". Apparently it is a template argument on the Nef_polyhedron_3" that defaults to `bool`. However the documentation also says it is not implemented and that you shouldn't mess with it. I am a bit confused why there is even an assertion on some unimplemented feature. I tried simply commenting out the assertion, but it simply goes on to fail at a later point.

I am using the following kernel and typedefs as it was the only example I could find that allowed doubles in the construction of the meshes.

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Nef_polyhedron_3<Kernel> Nef_polyhedron;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel> Polyhedron;
```

I used CGAL 4.6.3 installed with the exe installer. I have also tried the 4.7 beta and I get the same exception(at line 300 instead though).

Related github issue: https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues/353

**EDIT:** The issue turned out to be with the meshes. The meshes I were using had self intersections. Thus, even though is_valid, is_closed and is_triangular returned true, the mesh was in valid for conversion to a nef polyhedron. From CGAL 4.7. The Polygon mesh processing package has been introduced which contains [this](http://doc.cgal.org/4.7/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PkgPolygonMeshProcessing.html#ga0beba25d03a16010b20e2c9b6771cd12) which can be used to check for self intersections.

Comment: How did you convert your polyhedra to nef?

Comment: `if (poly->is_closed()) {
                return NefPolyhedron(poly);
    }`

Comment: Additionally i have check that is_valid and is_pure_triangle returns true.

Comment: I can't find the assertion that is raised in CGAL. Which version are you using? was is the exact assertion message?

Comment: I added the info in the question

Comment: I think I need input meshes. Could you post an [issue](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues)?